# Choosing multiple files with wizhook.getfilename VBA Access

Tags: vba, file, ms-access

I've been using the code below in order to get the name of a file. Is it possible to select multiple files with Wizhook? If not, is there a better choice? Bare in mind that i use Access and not Excel to script.

```
Public Function OpenFileDialog() As String
    Dim sFile$, sFilter$, sTitle$
    sFilter = "All Files (*.*)" 'Access Database (*.mdb)|Access 2007 Databases(*.accdb)"
    sTitle = "Choose the Back-End-File..."
    WizHook.Key = 51488399
    WizHook.GetFileName 0, "", sTitle, "", sFile, CurrentProject.Path, sFilter, 0, 0, 64, True
    Debug.Print sFile
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `WizHook` has cool stuff, you are probably better off using `Office.FileDialog`, which provides very good high-level API for dialogs.

[Application.FileDialog property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[FileDialog Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/filedialog-object-office)